# Call activerecord destroy without transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, transactions

I'd like to destroy an object and everything that is associated with it.
The problem is, the tree of `dependant: :destroy` runs very deep and the operation of destroying the toplevel object takes minutes.

What makes this worse (in this case), is Rails puts all of these destroys in a transaction, which can cause lock wait timeouts for other threads.

This is a special case where I'd like to have the cascading destroys, WITHOUT any transactional wrapper.

Can this be easily done?